# how to get text in nested div with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, lxml

the nested div

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">first part text</div>
    second part text
</div>
```

here's my code

```
infos = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "a"})
print(infos[0].getText())
```

The console print is `first part text` and `second part text` both. How to extract `second part text` only.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `find()` return the first element in the `find_all()`
2. Use `.` to find the next `div` in the `infos` tag and use `next_sibling` to find the text

---

```
infos = soup.find("div", {"class": "a"})
print(infos.div.next_sibling)
```

[image]